# Angular+ionic $http.get ng-repeat then check if the data in $cordovaSQLite

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, ionic-framework

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuG7d.png)

The book list is grab from the $http, then put the data into ng-repeat
However, i want to check if this book is already in $cordovaSQLite, then show "go",
if the book doesen't in the sqlite, then show "download" button

here is my code (if data already in sqlite then doesn't show the download button), but it doesn't work.

```
var theurl = 'http://server/api/book/getAll';
$http.get(theurl).then(function(res) {
  $scope.posts = res.data.posts;

  $scope.showDownloadBT = function(part){
    var result = true;
    var queryDR = "SELECT * FROM BookDownloaded WHERE bookId = ? AND page = ? ";
     $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, queryDR, [book_id, the_page]).then(function(res2) {
      if(res2.rows.length > 0) {
          result = false;
      }else{
          result = true;
      }
    }, function (err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
    return result;
  }
```

the view is:

```
<div class="item item-button-right" ng-repeat="eachPost in posts;">
    {{ eachPost.title }}
    <button class="button button-positive" ng-show="showDownloadBT(eachPost.part)">Download</button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions are asynchronous, so try a recursion on the function `showDownloadBT` and add a attribute in each post `showDownload`, like this:

```
var theurl = 'http://server/api/book/getAll';
$http.get(theurl).then(function(res) {
  $scope.posts = res.data.posts;
  var postList = res.data.posts;
  var i = 0;
  showDownloadBT(i)//call first time

  function showDownloadBT (index) {
    var queryDR = "SELECT * FROM BookDownloaded WHERE bookId = ? AND page = ? ";
    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, queryDR, [book_id, the_page]).then(function(res2) {
      if(res2.rows.length > 0) {
          postList[index].showDownload = false;
      }else{
          postList[index].showDownload = trues;
      }

      //  recursion
      i++;
      if (postList[i]) { //prevents stack overflow
        showDownloadBT(i);
      } else {
        $scope.posts = postList;// end of list
      }
    }, function (err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
  }
```

and in the HTML:

```
<div class="item item-button-right" ng-repeat="eachPost in posts;">
    {{ eachPost.title }}
    <button class="button button-positive" ng-show="eachPost.showDownload">Download</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: how do i call the "getBooksResponse" in ng-repeat?

Comment: It's a example, can be callback or a promisse... Can call this function where you currently call the `$http` function

Comment: Keep calm, I will refactor my answer

Comment: i got it!! the code is working correctly. thanks so much